# $E(X|Y)=E(X)$ for NOT independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

is there a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ with two NOT independent random variables $X,Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ ($X \in \mathcal L^1(P)$), such that

\begin{align}
E(X|Y)=E(X).
\end{align}

I was searching for a while, but I'm not able to find an example for the moment.

In addition to that, our professor mentioned, that all random variables $X,Y \in \mathcal L^2(P)$ with $E(X|Y)=E(X)$ are uncorrelated. How can I proof it?

Maybe someone can help me.

Greets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X\sim\mathcal{U}[-1;1]$  and $Y=X^2$ is an example of two dependent random variables in which:  $$\mathsf E(X)=0, \mathsf E(X\mid Y)=0$$

Now, if $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=\mathsf E(X)$, then the covariance is zero.$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y) ~&=~ \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y) \\[1ex]&=~ \mathsf E\Big(\mathsf E\big(X\mid Y\big)~Y\Big)-\mathsf E\Big(\mathsf E\big(X\big)~Y\Big) \\[1ex]&=~ \mathsf E\Big(\mathsf E\big(X\mid Y\big)~Y-\mathsf E\big(X\big)~Y\Big) \\[1ex] &=~ 0\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! So for $E(XY)=E(E(X|Y)Y)$ you used $E(XY|Y)=E(XY)$? So if we know that $E(X|Y)=E(X)$, we can conclude that also $E(XY|Y)=E(XY)$ holds? What is with the other implication: If we have two uncorrelated random variables $X'$ and $Y'$, does this mean, that $E(X'|Y')=E(X')$ is true? I don't think so but I can't find an example. Do you know one?

Comment: No $\mathsf E(XY) = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(XY\mid Y))$ by the Law of Iterated Expectation and $\mathsf E(XY\mid Y) = Y\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ because $Y$ is relatively constant with respect to itself.  So $\mathsf E(XY)=\mathsf E(Y\,\mathsf E(X\mid Y))$.